# Switching between different data presentations in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, rx-java, android-mapview

I'm  developing  the  application that  have  2  different  presentation  of the same list on  entities: showing  on  map  and  on list.

I'm  doing  the  next: making  api  call (rxjava+retrofit) to load  the entities on creating  my  activity. This  activity  contents ViewPager with  list  fragment  and  map  accordingly.

When data  loaded -  activity  tells  to   visible  fragment  to  show this  data. When  user  swiping  pages  - the  same downloaded  list  of  entities  should  be  shown  in appropriate  fragment. Also  data  should  be  reloaded when  user  makes  pull-to refresh   on  listfragment.

I'm  getting  the  problems  after  rotating screen  and sometimes after returning  from sleep  mode.

How  to  handle  correctly  the  common downloaded list with data  for  2  fragments?

Comment: You should provide some more information about your specific problem, what exactly is going on ? And please add some code snippets on how you load data initialize viewpager etc.

Comment: I think you have to paste your code here, so people can understand it better. @Elvira